Why is $Q^TQ$ not identity?
I am studying Linear algebra through MIT Opencourseware and solving the following problem:
(a) $p = A\hat{x}$ is the vector in $C(A)$ nearest to a give vector $b$. If $A$ has independent columns, what equation determines $\hat{x}$? What are all the vectors perpendicular to the error $e = b - A\hat{x}$? What goes wrong if the columns of $A$ are dependent?
I answered $R^{-1}Q^{-1}\mathbb{b} = \mathbb{\hat{x}}$ and it was correct.
However the following question makes me complicated.
(b) Suppose $A = QR$ where $Q$ has orthonormal columns and $R$ is upper triangular invertible. Find $\hat{x}$ and $p$ in terms of $Q$ and $R$ and $b$ (not $A$).
I solved it by the following process:
$$
\begin{align}
p & = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T\mathbb{b} \\
& = QR(R^TQ^TQR)^{-1}R^TQ^T\mathbb{b} \\
& = QR(R^TR)^{-1}R^TQ^T\mathbb{b} \\
& = QRR^{-1}(R^T)^{-1}R^TQ^T\mathbb{b} \\
& = QQ^T \mathbb{b}
\end{align}$$
From the last row, I thought $QQ^T$ can be $I$ since $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix. However the solution says $QQ^T$ is not necessarily $I$ although $Q^TQ$ is $I$. Can anyone give a proper solution for this problem?

Is $Q$ necessarily square?

No it isn't. however if it matters, can $Q^TQ$ be $I$?

You're told that $Q$ has orthonormal columns. Suppose, for example, $Q$ consists of the first two columns of the $3\times3$ identity matrix. Then $Q^TQ$ is the $2\times2$ identity; but $QQ^T$ is not the $3\times3$ identity. When $Q$ is square and orthonormal, you get $Q^TQ=QQ^T=I$.

Oh actually the size of $I$ matters! Thanks :)
